# Calculate area (integral)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Calculate the area of the domain bounded by $OX$, the curve $y = \ln x$ and the tangent of $y$ $(d):\:...$  knowing that $A(0, 0) \in d$.

I tried to use the formula $(d):y-y_0 = m(x-x_0)$, where $m$ would be the derivative of $\ln x$ in $x_0=0$ but it has no derivative in $x_0=0$...

Also, I know that the integral should look like this $\int _0^b\:\left|f\left(x\right)-\ln \left(x\right)\right|$

EDIT: The answer is $\frac{e}{2}-1$ if that helps in any way.

Comment: OX is x-axis, right?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T(x_0, f(x_0))$ be the intersection point of $d$ and $y$. $A(0, 0) \in d$ so $d = mx $ and $m = f'(x)$.  $T(x_0, f(x_0)) \in d \implies f(x_0)=f'(x_0)\cdot x_0 \implies x = e.$ So $(d):y = \frac{x}{e}$

So we have to calculate $\int_{0}^{e}\frac{x}{e}dx-\int_{1}^{e}lnxdx$

Answer (score 1):

Make a picture of this.

Looks to me like it will be easier to integrate with respect to $y.$

$y = \ln x\\
x = e^y$

$d$ Is the line tangent to the curve $x = e^y$ that goes through the point $(0,0)$

$\frac {x}{y} = \frac {d}{dy} e^y = e^y = x\\
\frac {x}{y} = x\\
y = 1 $

$d$ is the line $x = ey$

$\int_0^1 e^y - ey \ dy\\
e^y - \frac 12 e y^2|_0^1\\
\frac 12 e - 1$